# EntityFramework 7 Migration Initial Create

Tags: assemblies, entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-core

Im trying to run dnx ef migrations Add IntitialDatabase.  However, it fails to run and gives the error `"Could not load Assembly 'MyProject.'  Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'MyProject.'"`

Where is it looking for this reference so that I can correct the mismatch?

Comment: Does the said assembly contain a startup class?

Comment: @Lutando Yes, the project contains a startup class

Comment: Are they under the same namespace? (your Startup project should be under MyProject. namespace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely enough this error was the result of my having an incomplete constructor in one of my controllers.  When I added the missing closing bracket and ran the add migration again it completed successfully without the assembly error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set as startup project, which the project in solution add migration. Then you can change. Right click on project and select "set as startup project".

Comment: Or other way, right click solution and select "Properties". After u see "Multiple startup projects", chose and there see your projects on your solution.  You can set whatever you want as a startup project.